# does spark 3.5 support text read with multi char line separator like "I,"

Tags: apache-spark

was trying to load text file with multi char line delimiter . is it supported in spark if yes please let us know spark version to use

we tried with spark 2.x version as its not available we were doing pre processing before read , which impacting our loads
spark.read.text(path, linesep"I,")

Answer (score 0):

It is supported also in 2.x version (at least in latest, 2.4.7):

```
// File 'test.csv':
// a|,b|,cc|,dd

scala> spark.read.format("text").option("lineSep", "|,").load("test.csv").show() 
+-----+                                                                          
|value|                                                                          
+-----+                                                                          
|    a|                                                                          
|    b|                                                                          
|   cc|                                                                          
|   dd|                                                                          
+-----+
```